# Is a one-line python closure possible without lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, closures

Is it possible to write the following closure in Python in only one line (as an expression that, for example, could be passed to `map()`) without using lambda?

```
from operator import add, eq

def sum_equal_to_target(target):
    def f(pair):
        return eq(target, add(*pair))
    return f

sum_equal_to_target = lambda pair: eq(target, add(*pair))
sum_equal_to_target = lambda pair: target == (pair[0] + pair[1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible (by using `exec`), but not advisable -- there are [many disadvantages](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-evalexec-is-bad.html), including the loss of readability:

```
from operator import add, eq

exec('def sum_equal_to_target(target):\n    def f(pair):\n        return eq(target, add(*pair))\n    return f')

print(list(map(sum_equal_to_target(7), [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])))
# [False, True, False]
```

---

Note that `lambda` functions are Python's way of making (simple) one-line
anonymous functions. AFAICS, to do this *without* lambda requires a hack like `exec`.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for creativity, even if you're kind of cheating. :)

Comment: Given the parameters of your question, I don't think there is a solution without cheating :)

Comment: That's why I asked. :)